# Theano Neural network implementation for a chess engine

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, theano

**Intro**

Please bear with me as this will be a long post.

Basically I am trying to implement a Chess engine using NN. My idea is to have a single layer NN trained based on millions of positions (I split the file, and each file consist of few thousand positions). The input of my NN is 64 nodes (1 for each square), and the value of the inputs are between `[-6, 6]`, 13 pieces including no piece.

I am trying to implement a single hidden layer NN using Theano. I read over the tutorial on Theano, and I have a rough understanding of NN (I took the ML course taught by Andrew Ng). I think it should be enough to accomplish what I want to do.

**My input files**

Each FEN file consist of few thousand positions. I used stockfish to analyse each position, and obtained a static evaluation score Y. After, I converted each FEN position into a `1*64` X vector like so:

```
X=0,3,0,-3,0,-6,0,-4,0,3,0,0,0,-1,-1,0,0,0,0,0,-1,-2,0,0,1,-2,0,0,0,0,0,-1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,4,0,0,4,0,6

Y=332
```

I have 5 million of these.

**My problem**

I am having a hard time actually implementing the training section of NN in Theano. Here is a snippet of my NN code (mostly its taken from the tutorial, if i use `...` then it means I have the same code as the tutorial http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/logreg.html#logreg).

```
class LogisticRegression(object):
    def __init__(self, input, n_in, n_out):
        ...

class HiddenLayer(object):
    def __init__(self, rng, input, n_in, n_out, W=None, b=None,
                 activation=T.tanh):
        ...

class MLP(object):
    def __init__(self, rng, input, n_in, n_hidden, n_out):
        ...

def main():
    rng = numpy.random.RandomState(1234)
    x=numpy.loadtxt('x.txt', delimiter=',')
    y=numpy.loadtxt('y.txt', delimiter=',')
    learning_rate=0.01 
    L1_reg=0.00 
    L2_reg=0.0001 
    n_epochs=1000,
    n_hidden=2000
    index = T.lscalar()
    x = T.matrix('x')
    y = T.ivector('y')
    n_train_batches = x.shape[1]
    classifier = MLP(rng=rng, input=x, n_in=64, n_hidden=n_hidden, n_out=1)
    cost = (
        classifier.negative_log_likelihood(y)
        + L1_reg * classifier.L1
        + L2_reg * classifier.L2_sqr
    )
    gparams = [T.grad(cost, param) for param in classifier.params]
    updates = [
        (param, param - learning_rate * gparam)
        for param, gparam in zip(classifier.params, gparams)
    ]
    print('... training')

   ## I AM HAVING TROUBLE HERE IMPLEMENTING THE TRAINING PART OF THIS CODE
```

I understand I am asking for a lot of help, and I thank you for being patient reading my post. But I will really appreciate it if someone can show me how this is done, or even point me towards the right direction. This project is not work related or school related, but it is still very important to me because I really want to see it through.

Thanks

Comment: What makes this different from the tutorial you are following, which makes it impossible to do the training like there?

Comment: Possibly because I don't really know what I am doing. I know python, I know machine learning on Octave, but I seem to have trouble putting the two together. I feel like I am trying to build a building using another building's blueprint.

Comment: the assignments on Coursera provided by Andrew have most of the scaffolding implemented, all I had to do was fill in the blanks. But this time I am trying to build things from scratch, in a different environment. I am copying different tutorial, trying to make it work. But I think it could be the Theano's specific syntax thats stopping me from implementing it.

Comment: For example, in the tutorial I posted, it has validation_frequency, epoch, minibatch and all that stuff. All I want to do is train my NN based on the data I provide. And I don't mean to sulk, but the tutorial seems overly complex. But I also don't know how to simplify it.